# Function keys shifted to the right in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, function-keys

My function keys in Outlook have shifted five keys to the right. For example, if I assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> as the shortcut for one of the color categories, then the actual working shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>. Also, the shortcut for toggling the ribbon would normally be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, but here I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>. It only seems to affect the function keys when the shortcut uses a combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>F#</kbd> - the function keys work fine on their own, for example <kbd>F1</kbd> for help, <kbd>F3</kbd> to search, and so on.

This issue has been found on multiple machines (one running Outlook 2013, and two running 2016).

The function keys work as normal in all other applications, including other Office programs.

What could cause this?